# Pip is not recognizing the install command (Windows 7, Python 3.3)

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am trying to install Python programs using Pip. Python recognizes the pip module, but none of the pip commands. Has anyone else had this problem?

For example,
[image]

Comment: Run `pip install python-etsy` on cmd not Python shell.

Answer (score 1):

`pip` is a *command-line tool*, that also happens to be a module you can import.

To install a package, execute the command-line tool, not the module. E.g. run `pip` in your terminal or console, not in Python itself:

```
$ pip install python-etsy
```

You tried to execute the command-line syntax in a Python shell; that's not valid Python syntax.

As of Python 3.4, `pip` is included with Python, but to ensure you get to use the right version, you need to use the Python `py` command to invoke it:

```
py -3 -m pip install python-etsy
```

See the [*Installing Python Modules* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/installing/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

To use 'pip' in windows you have to change the directory to the folder 'pip' is installed in and then execute it.

In Python 2.7 'pip' and 'easy_install' are in 'Python27\Scripts' as far as i remember 'pip' should be in 'Python3x\Lib\site-packages'. Just navigate your cmd to the right folder with the command 'cd'.

```
open cmd
type 'cd C:\Python3x\Lib\site-packages' with x replaced by your version.
type 'pip.exe install requests' or 'easy_install.exe requests'
```